# How to remove tenting from specific vias?

Tags: pcb, altium, via

I defined a SolderMaskExpansion rule in Altium and with that way all vias are tented. But I want to remove tenting for some of the vias. I mean, I want some vias to be tented and some vias to be non-tented, but I don't want to delete the rule while doing this. Can I do this with Top & Bottom Solder layer. Or how do I do this more easily? [image]

Comment: Put an exclusion in the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Altium you can have overriding rules (just add a new one and change the priority), if you have a way of defining the segregation of the vias in this way.

Otherwise you can select the vias you want (if selecting many, make sure to use the Via filter in the properties pane when selecting nothing, then select an area on the board), then in the properties pane of the selected vias, select Manual for solder mask expansion and untick tented.

Comment: I deleted the rule and select all the vias manually using via filter. This is the best method for now. Thanks.

Comment: @harmonica, another way is make the vias you want to have special handling with a slightly different diameter, like 0.201 mm instead of 0.2 mm. Then you can write a rule that only affects the 0.201 mm vias. But the fab will use the exact same drill for them because drills don't come in 1 um size increments.

Comment: Smart, but if the design is taken over you have the possible bug of someone saying "this doesn't exist, I'm cleaning that up" and resetting the via diameter to 0.2mm - potentially breaking some requirements without any way to trace it back easily (since there is no built-in way to document this link)